# Prove $\frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{3}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^3}+\cdots$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

> Prove $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{3}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^3}+\cdots$$ converges, where the sums are for all primes $p$.

[I've found in this link that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes#Euler.27s_proof) $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{3}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^3}+\cdots$$

converges to $K$, where $K<1$.

I know that $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6},$

[because see Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and [specific values of Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values).

Therefore also $$\sum_p \frac{1}{p^k}\le \sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}\le\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

for all $k\ge 3$, $k\in\mathbb Z.$

Comment: $\sum_{p}p^{-2}\leq \sum_{n\geq1}n^{-2}<\infty,$ so this sum does converge.

Comment: An explicit form is given by $-C$, in (4) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html), which can be shown using the relation (6), taking the limit as $s\to 1$, and using proper asymptotics for $\ln(\zeta (s))$ and $\frac{P(s)}{s}$.

Answer (score 8):

Notice that
$$\sum_{p} \frac{1}{p^s}\lt\zeta(s)-1$$
so your sum is bounded from above by
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{s=2}^\infty(\zeta(s)-1)
&=\sum_{s=2}^\infty \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}}-1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\\[9pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
and so your sum is less than one, and must also trivially be positive, so it converges.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer. I hope you don't mind I adjusted the formatting.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks, and of course I don't mind! :)

Answer (score 8):

Throwing in all integers greater than $1$ still gives a convergent series:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac1{k\,p^k}
&\le\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{k\,n^k}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left[\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)-\frac1n\right]\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^m\left[\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)-\frac1n\right]\\[3pt]
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[\log(m)-H_m+1\right]\\[9pt]
&=1-\gamma
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Since $2$ is the smallest prime, we can see by comparing terms that

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}>\sum_p \frac{1}{p^3}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^3}>\sum_p \frac{1}{p^4}$$

and so on.

So it follows that

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{3}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^3}+\cdots < \frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^3}+\cdots <$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}+\cdots =\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots\right)\sum_p\frac{1}{p^2}=$$
$$\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}<\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} =\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Since the sum is increasing, the presence of an upper bound means it converges.

Comment: $$\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^2}<\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}-1=$$

$$=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$$

Comment: [Also see this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047102/is-displaystyle-sum-p-in-mathcal-p-frac1p%c2%b2-frac-pi%c2%b26?rq=1)

Comment: @user263326 Good catch. I mixed up those two sums at the end.

Comment: You could've written, e.g., $$\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^2}<\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}-1=$$ $$=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-1$$ to get that, e.g., $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^{2}}+\frac{1}{3}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^{3}}+\cdots<1$$

Answer (score 2):

Since the terms are positive we can rearrange them
$$K:=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{p^k}=
\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(1/p)^k}{k}=\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\left[-\ln\left(1-(1/p)\right)-(1/p)\right].$$
Now note that $-\ln(1-x)-x\leq x^2$ for $x\in [0,1/2]$ (because the derivative of the difference is $\frac{x(1-2x)}{1-x}\geq 0$) which implies that
$$K\leq \sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{p^2}\leq \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1<1.$$